# How do I claim the money that I spent few years ago for the company now

Tags: travel, financial-record

Few years ago I had to make international travel and I've spent money which I have to claim after the travel is done.

So I had initiated the Reimbursement claim. some claims were reimbursed while some came back but I forgot to follow up.

But It's been years , If I go back they'd probably reject saying the period to claim it back is over and we're in different financial year and we're sorry lilke that.

But I'm in a financial distress ,  so how can I convince them to reimburse me now?

How shall I approach this - please guide.

Comment: This really depends on company policy and why they rejected some claims in the first place. Please clarify what was the reject reason. I used to work for a company whose policy was that you must claim the expense within 60 days after the travel. If that's the policy your company has, you have no hope.

Comment: There are situations where you can make claims for up to 5 or up to 6 years. So if it happened “years ago” it might or might not fall into this category.

Comment: How much money are we talking about compared to your paycheck?

Comment: If they rejected it then, with all the facts conveniently at hand, I would be *very* surprised if they approved it now. Go ahead and ask, but please look for other solutions to your cash flow problem because this is unlikely to solve it.

Comment: @sf02 - It's a month's paycheck

Answer (score 6):

**TL;DR** - While this in absolutely dependent on company policy, there is no harm in asking.

To elaborate: You made the travel on business requirement and the expenses are business expense, so company shall reimburse you. However, since it has been long, the claim window might have expired. Nevertheless, there's no harm in asking. Talk to your manager and/or the travel/finance department, and mention about the situation. They may approve an exception, provided you submit the revised claim. There's no guarantee that it will be approved, but there's no harm in asking either.

Go ahead and connect with the required people, and hope they'll understand and process this.

Comment: I am not sure there is no harm. The accounting department may have to recover all the data (including the receipts) to verify the claim. This adds to their work load. (supposed to be un-necessary in the first place). They won't be happy.

Comment: @Nobody Agree. that's why I said, it may need exceptional approval to get this done. If they are not ready to do this, or not possible, they'll reject the claim. Also, IMHO, "harm" =/= "inconvenience". YMMV.

Comment: I feel like any reasonable company would value making the employee whole from an honest mistake over the small time and cost it would take to do so. Hiring people is expensive.